# Would Azure private marketplace be an option for storing server gold images for infrastructure deployments?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd, infrastructure-as-code, azure-marketplace

Interested in getting feedback on pros/cons for this solution for storing server images? Any alternatives and their pro/cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private Azure Marketplace is not an option for storing custom (gold) images for infrastructure deployments. As per the Azure documentation, custom images cannot be included in Private Azure Marketplace.

[image]

However, Azure Compute Gallery can be used to share custom images. The steps to create and share custom images using Azure Compute Gallery are provided in the context.

As for alternatives, other options for storing server images include Azure Blob Storage and Azure Managed Disks. The pros and cons of these alternatives depend on specific use cases and requirements. For example, maybe cost-effective and offers high availability, but requires additional steps to manage the images and create VMs from them.

References:

- [Frequently asked questions about governance and control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/governance-control-faq#can-we-include-custom-images-in-private-azure-marketplace)
- [Windows Server in Azure Stack marketplace FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/ruggedized/operator/azure-stack-windows-server-faq-tzl#windows-server-in-azure-stack-marketplace-faq)
- [Govern/Control/Use Azure Private Marketplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/create-manage-private-azure-marketplace-new#private-azure-marketplace-value-and-benefits)